# How to manipulate the colors of the auto-expanding selection in edit-text

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin

[image]

In the gif you can see on double tap, the automatic expansion for the string which happens in a different color (light blue?), I have not defined this color anywhere, which looks odd. How do we manipulate this property?

I have tried many highlight properties like colorControlActivated, Normal, Highlight etc but it does not affect this at all!

I am expecting to be able to manipulate the auto-expansion animation color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:** This happens due to the property `singleLine="true"` && `inputType="text"`. Better way is to use `maxLines = "1"` and set input type to text programatically